# update links using win32com where excel is linked with multiple sources

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

I am using win32com.client to open Excel with

```
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename,UpdateLinks=False, ReadOnly=True)
```

Sometimes this generates an alert with the following text:

"This workbook contains one or more links that cannot be
updated." & options are: "Continue", and "Edit Links").

This stops the script until I handle the dialogue box manually which is not preferred.

I want to continue as if "Continue" had been
clicked, or to suppress the whole dialogue box,  I can't find a way to do this.

Searching the Stackoverflow forums, I've seen the following suggestions:

```
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
excel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
```

I've tried each of these (immediately after the excel variable is
assigned) and neither has the desired effect, separately or together.

As suggested in other forums I have also tried to open excel & save & then again reopen with python, which is also not working.

```
wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Path to file,UpdateLinks = False)
ws = wb.Worksheets('XYZ')
wb.Close(SaveChanges=1)
excel.Visible = False
excel.ScreenUpdating = False 
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
excel.AskToUpdateLinks = False

wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Path to file)
ws = wb.Worksheets('XYZ')
```

Does anyone know a solution that works? anything will do either break link or continue.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
excel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
```

As far as I know, the above turns off the prompt and automatically update external links as a file is open. Try use below:

```
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(Path to file,UpdateLinks=0)
```